# How to display facets in tabs

Tags: views, search

i am using Search API and Facets API to display facets based results .

i wonder how to display the facets in tabs. Is there a module for it.

BBCGoodFood is doing that already . (done with Drupal)

http://www.bbcgoodfood.com/search/recipes?query=asian
[image]

Any clue?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the aptly named [Facet API Tabs](https://drupal.org/project/facetapi_tabs) module.

> This module adds the option of displaying search facets as tabs. It's heavily
>   based on the "links" widget that comes with FacetAPI, and has just altered the
>   rendering rules of the links, as well as added the "All" tab.